# Equivalent to product flavors in non-Android Gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I'm creating a desktop Java app and would like to create two versions: free and paid. The difference is mainly in which resource files are included (at a future date, it may involve different code as well, but not right now).

I've read about [Android build variants](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) allowing for just this sort of thing through "product flavors". However, this seems to be a feature unique to the `android` plugin, which is obviously not available on the desktop.

Is there an equivalent to these product flavors that does not depend on the `android`plugin?

If it helps, my end goal is to find a way that I can run the Gradle `build` task and output two different versions of the app, which is my understanding of what the Android build variants accomplishes.

Answer (score 9):

Sure you can use `sourceSets` and customize the `Jar` tasks to accomplish the same effect.

```
group 'com.jbirdvegas.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

// adding the java plugin add the `jar` task to the build task graph
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

/**
 * SourceSets allows different builds to have their own
 * code.  If main and flavorOne contain com.foo.Bar then
 * the `flavorOne` jar will contain the file specified by
 * the `flavorOne` source set files.
 */
sourceSets {
    main {
        // you could also do per sourceSet resources if needed
        java.srcDir 'src/main/java'
    }
    flavorOne {
        java.srcDir 'src/flavorOne/java'
    }
    flavorTwo {
        java.srcDir 'src/flavorTwo/java'
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the first flavor's jar when the Java plugin's `Jar`
 * task is called.  Since the `jar` task depends on `flavorOne` task
 * this task will run before the generic `jar` task which produces
 * the base .jar artifact.
 */
task flavorOne(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.flavorOne.output
    classifier = 'flavorOneJar'
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "de.jeha.photo.mosaic.cli.Main"
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the second flavor's jar when the Java plugin's `Jar`
 * task is called.  `flavorTwo` can run before `flavorOne` because
 * both must just run before the `jar` task (base artifact)
 */
task flavorTwo(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.flavorTwo.output
    classifier = 'flavorTwoJar'
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "de.jeha.photo.mosaic.cli.Main"
    }
}

// be sure to build all flavors whenever the `jar` task runs
jar.dependsOn flavorOne, flavorTwo

dependencies {
    // you can declare different dependencies per sourceSets
    flavorOneCompile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    flavorTwoCompile 'com.something:else:1.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

/**
 * if you want to have specific control over the main jar's
 * build then you could configure the main jar as needed.
 * This is the equivalent of the `flavorBlah` tasks except
 * this task was added for us by the `java` plugin.  Changes
 * here will only affect the main jar built from `sourceSet.main`
 *
 * Think of this as the default where other `productFlavors` are
 * completely divorced from this jar's configuration.
 */
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes "Main-Class": "de.jeha.photo.mosaic.cli.Main"
    }
}
```

Then we can see the different builds. Our flavors and the `main` source set jar.

```
$ ls -l build/libs/
-rw-r--r--  1 jbirdvegas  63209268   1.3K Jan  6 08:58 my-sweet-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-flavorOneJar.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jbirdvegas  63209268   302B Jan  6 08:58 my-sweet-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT-flavorTwoJar.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 jbirdvegas  63209268    18K Jan  6 08:58 my-sweet-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Added more comments and added a jar closure to show how to apply configurations to the main jar.  This is the equivalent method for the `flavorBlah` tasks.  I can explain any part further it would help

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! I'll wait a bit to see if other answers emerge.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: how to choose a certain flavour and get IntelliJ IDEA support? I mean, I want autocompletion to work with libraries I've included through `flavorXCompile`.

Comment: @Miha_x64, you might be able to do something like `configurations.compile.extendsFrom flavorX`

Comment: @JBirdVegas I'm getting 'Could not find method extendsFrom() for arguments [task ':someFlavor'] on configuration ':compile' of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.'

Comment: Odd, perhaps it wants you to do it in the blocks `configurations { compile { extendsFrom(flavorX) } }`.  The method definitely exists: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/dependency-management/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/configurations/DefaultConfiguration.java#L278

Comment: @JBirdVegas same. :'(

Comment: is any plugins out there to simpilify this work just like android did?